# Bazaar bound branch commit-and-update

Tags: bazaar

I use bzr for websites. I have all my current ones set up so the master branch is kept on the server by having them bound. This means when I commit locally, the changes are automatically pushed out. All good so far.

But I still have to call an update on the remote server. While I can see this being great for some people, I'm finding it increasingly annoying.

Is there a way to commit, push and do a remote update all at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic updates to the production website is bad, even with a VCS to go back up IMO.  Anyway, did you looked at [this](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/bzr.dev/en/user-reference/bzr_man.html#hooks)?

Answer (score 6):

there are 2 plugins for bzr that could help you:

push-and-update: https://launchpad.net/bzr-push-and-update/

bzr-upload: https://launchpad.net/bzr-upload

The latter does not require to keep the branch with full history on the server at all.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a script? e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
bzr commit $*
bzr pull
bzr push
```

Put it in your PATH and give it an obvious name like "bzrsync". It's simple, but should save you a few keystrokes...

Answer (score 1):

bzr commit on a bound branch uploads your changes but does not update the working tree of the master branch.

After your commit, bzr push should cause the working tree to update remotely.

Comment: Actually, `bzr push` doesn't cause the remote working tree to be updated either, that needs a `bzr pull` from the other side or one of the plugins bialix mentioned.